# How to change canvas image via script

Tags: c#, user-interface, canvas, unity-game-engine

I have a script, which change texture of the object (like a plane on the TV) fixed times per second:

```
public Texture[] frames;                // array of textures
public float framesPerSecond = 2.0f;    // delay between frames

void Update()
{
    int index = (int)(Time.time * framesPerSecond) % frames.Length;
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = frames[index];
}
```

With this script I can change texture of plane, quad, etc. But I need to change it for canvas image. I can't change "Image" script. Should I access value "Source Image" of this script? Would it be correct?

And is so, how can I access `Image` component? I can't write this:

`Image image = GetComponent<Image>();`

[image]

Comment: I can't test the following that's why i'm not putting it as an answer. You need to add `using Unityengine.UI` and the you can use something along the lines of  `GetComponent<Image>().setImage = someImage;`

Comment: @Rana I don't know where you got setImage from....

Comment: it was out of my head XD. I said it was "along the lines"... I checked you have property called `sprite`. So you could do `GetComponent<Image>().sprite = someSprite;` I might be wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `Image`, you need to **convert** `Texture` to `Sprite` then **change** `image.sprite` property

**Method 1** (**Image**)

```
public Texture[] frames;                // array of textures
public float framesPerSecond = 2.0f;    // delay between frames
Image image = null;

void Start()
{
    //Get Image Reference
    image = gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();
}

void Update()
{
        int index = (int)(Time.time * framesPerSecond) % frames.Length;

        //Convert Texture to Sprite
        Sprite s = Sprite.Create((Texture2D)frames[index], new Rect(0, 0, frames[index].width, frames[index].height),
                                Vector2.zero, 0);
        image.sprite = s; //Change The Image
}
```

**Method 2** (**RawImage**) `image.texture`
If you use `RawImage`, you **just** need to change the `image.texture` property.

```
public Texture[] frames;                // array of textures
public float framesPerSecond = 2.0f;    // delay between frames
RawImage image = null; 

void Start()
{
 //Get Raw Image Reference
 image = gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>();
}

void Update()
{
  int index = (int)(Time.time * framesPerSecond) % frames.Length;
  image.texture = frames[index]; //Change The Image
}
```

I suggest you go with **method 2**. This means that you have to **delete** the current Image in your scene. Then go to **GameObject**->**UI**->**Raw Image** and **create** a `RawImage`. Raw Image is **efficient** in this case because you are always **changing** the image. Using **method 1** is **slower** and will unleash **garbage collector** in your **game/app**.